# How does an anti-g overall work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, applied-physics

Assuming that a human being would be exposed by 10g in a jetplane. This g-force will cause health risks without a proper g-protection. But with an anti-g vest such health risks can be minimized. One can note that current rollercoasters are not exceeding 5g. For waterslides the Maximum tolerable g value is even lower.

Recently a vertical Loop slide (it is called "Skycalibre") was invented. This waterslide has g-Forces up to 6g. Can it be that the capsule of this waterslide is like an anti-g-protecting Overall?

Now the question: How does g-force protection work? Is it possible to construct anti-g Overalls that can be regulated by a mechanism (for example by electrorheological materials?)

I know that the anti-g Overalls are very tight such that the blood flow in the body is manipulated.

Comment: It makes a difference if the person is sitting or supine. If  sitting, the need is to prevent blood flow away from head to lower extremeties. If someone is floating in water, and the person + water is subjected to high-g, they can tolerate more.

Comment: It depends how long too, I think I have heard that car collisions are as high as 42 G, but just for a split second.

Comment: @EdYablecki: There's a lot going on inside the cabin when a car collides. What does a head weigh - 12lbs? That's a 500lb force being applied for a fraction of a second. Ouch. And that doesn't count the rest of the body. Without air bags and seat belts, it's a "life changing event".

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, I just did a calculation and it would require a speed of 478 mph and a stop time of 0.2 seconds. I am assuming that the stop time has to be even smaller then 0.2 to reach 42 G. Be like a 200 mph car hitting a brick wall.

Comment: @EdY Don't mistake peak acceleration for average acceleration. The former can be several times the latter without any special assumptions.